# How to handle php sessions with design patterns

Tags: design-patterns, php

and thanks you in advance for any help or insight you can provide. I took a look on this site, and around the internet but was not able to really find an answer to my question..

How could php sessions be best handled while keeping loose coupling within design patterns?

I understand that sessions are global and that you could create a registry pattern, however this defeats the idea of loose-coupling, or that is how I understand it anyway.

It also interferes with testing objects as well.

So, is the answer to the question, yes Registry pattern. Or are there other ways to handle sessions in php with keeping to the idea of loose coupling and ease of testing.

Comment: Wrap it in an object which lets you get and set data? You don't even have to use `session_start`, i.e. PHP's session implementation. Just some storage backend coupled with setting a cookie.

Comment: That way you can provide a mock that doesn't rely on any back end storage for use in your testing.

Comment: Thanks Deceze and Orangepill. Those are some great idea's.

Answer (score 0):

You can store any value using a session. You have to start the session with `session_start();` in the beginning of the page.

After that you can store a value in the session. for example `SESSION['variable_name'] = "your value";`. Afterwards you can get this value in any page.

Retrieve a value from the session like this: `echo SESSION['variable_name'];`. This will display your value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the OP is aware of how a session works. His question is about using it in conjunction with design patterns.

Comment: Yeah, I am aware how sessions work within PHP, thank you for your time none the less.